# Why does Pages.app connect to a server through https and keep the connection open?

Tags: macos, privacy, iwork-pages, iwork

Every time i start up the program Pages (iWork) it connects to a server through https. What is going on? Why would Apple do this? I use no features under Pages that could warrant this behaviour.

It connects to IP address 2.22.240.224 on port 443 and keeps the connection open until i close the application.

All the info i can get from Wireshark is a bunch of Apple-related domain names.

**Edit:** The same thing happens with Numbers. I have disabled "Documents & Data" on iCloud so that shouldn't be the reason why.

**Edit 2:** The programs in the iWork suite stopped doing this after recent updates so it's not an issue anymore.

Comment: iCloud document storage? [This thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/262114-why-do-my-tests-contact-http-configuration-apple-com-or-what-iss-dmconfig.html) on OS X programming mentions the host name in the SSL certificate shown when accessing that IP on the default HTTPS port. iCloud is the successor to .mac.

Comment: I don't have "Documents & Data" enabled. I can't open or save documents on iCloud through Pages. You're probably right about it being iCloud related though. This sucks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran Charles to see what it was requesting, and it's "configuration.apple.com".  It looks like it's unrelated to iCloud, instead it's to check software updates.  And it's been around for quite some time.

http://www.macintouch.com/readerreports/ilife06/topic4096.html